# Describe Images(AMI) with tag values using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ami

I have a boto3 script that describes images.

However, I want to customize the script so that it shows me only the value of the tag that is the Name of the AMI.

Currently its displaying:

```
([{u'Value': 'NAME OF AMI', u'Key': 'Name'}], 'ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'available')
```

But I want something like this:

```
**Name :'NAME OF AMI', 'ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'available'**
```

Here is my script:

```py
    import boto3
    import sys
    import pprint
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    response = client.describe_images(Owners=['self'])
    for ami in response['Images']:
        print (ami['Tags'], ami['ImageId'], ami['State'])
```

Comment: This is not an AWS problem, this is just a JSON parsing problem, please update the tags accordingly.

Comment: let the brackets be there.. I dnt want to display Value and Key attribute.. I jst want to display the AMI name.. Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple Tags on an AMI. This code will display the Value of the tag that has a Key of `Name` (and it will also show the `Name` of the AMI that normally appears as "AMI Name" in the console, which is a different name!):

```py
import boto3
import sys
import pprint
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.describe_images(Owners=['self'])
for ami in response['Images']:
    if 'Tags' in ami:
      name = [tag['Value'] for tag in ami['Tags'] if tag['Key'] == 'Name'][0]
    else:
      name = ''
    print (name, ami['Name'], ami['ImageId'], ami['State'])
```